# Virtualbox guest additions completely breaks graphics on Windows 10 preview

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-10-preview, guest-additions

Facing the issue with latest Virtual Box 4.3.28, VM of following config:

- intel i5 vPro 2 cores.
- 2800MB RAM
- 3D & 2D acceleration enabled, 256MB graphics memory.
- 25GB storage(Fixed size, Not dynamic).

(P.S. - Selected the Windows 10 option while creating the VM)

Every single time I try to install guest additions, the graphics completely messes up. Getting blank boxes all over.

P.P.S - Also updated graphics driver on host. Re-created VM from scratch after this. No change.

Answer (score 3):

Please disable the 3D acceleration to see whether it help.  This is an experimental feature that encountered problems in different Linux distributions.  It might have problem to Windows 10 Preview as well.

Comment: Oh? I thought it wouldn't work without 3D acceleration. Have you tried this? Will give it a shot.

Comment: Haven't try Windows 10 but try Windows 8, works well w/o 3D acceleration.  The performance is not fast but at least it works fine.

Comment: This worked - thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem in VirtualBox with a Windows 10 Virtual Machine with Guest Additions installed, it (the graphics messing up by displaying black all over) seems to only happen with HTML content (Windows Search, Edge/IE Browser, etc.) when the VM's 2D Acceleration setting is enabled.

**Follow these steps:**

- Shutdown the VM.
- Disable the 2D Acceleration in the VM's setting in Virtual Box.
- Turn in back on.